# Spring transaction with restful application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm working on spring boot and I need to clarify something regarding to `transaction` management.

For example, I do have 2 classes that run two separate jobs (the first job is to create profile on database and the second job is to call restful application also profile creation but on different system).

This 2 jobs must be in transactional. Both success needed. It should not create any profile on any data store if one of the job is fails)

Since I'm really new in this **Spring**. I hope to get suggestion and need to know what is the best practice for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). I suggest to make a `facade service` to join the logic of two services. Services must be separate, because working with profiles and communicating with other system are different parts of business logic.

For example, there are `ProfileService` and `OuterService` to work with profiles and to outer communication. You can write `SomeFacadeService` to join two methods and wrap it in one transaction. Default propagation of `@Transactional` is `REQUIRED`. So transaction will be created on method `SomeFacadeService.doComplexJob` and methods `profileService.createProfile` and `outerService.doOuterJob` will join the current transaction. If exception occurs in one of them whole `SomeFacadeService.doComplexJob` will be rolled back.

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {
@Autowired
            SomeFacadeService someFacadeService ;

    @RequestMapping("/someMapping")
    public void doSomeJob() {
        someFacadeService.doComplexJob();
    }
}

@Service
        public class SomeFacadeService {
            @Autowired
            ProfileService profileService;
            @Autowired
            OuterService outerService;

            @Transactional
            public void doComplexJob() {
                profileService.createProfile();
                outerService.doOuterJob();
            }
        }

        @Service 
        public class ProfileService {
            @Transactional
            public void createProfile() {
                // create profile logic
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @doge, testing this approach now and will share the update!

Comment: Sorry @doge, I need a quick clarification. On the outerService.doOuterJob(), should if return Boolean to indicate the result of the process?

Comment: No, if you do not need result for some other reason. Just throwing an exception is enough.